# How to call a method from adapter in activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, adapter

I just want to call a method (which is declared in an adapter) from an activity . Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: PASS Context in adapter constructor , then start activity

Comment: Yes, why not? What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: can you help me with any example ?

Comment: `adapterObject.methodToCall()`.

Comment: you can use interface based callbacks if you like!  i use it in my recyclerView adapters mostly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to call a method from adapter in activity :
1. Using your adapter object in activity. You can easily call your adapter method.

Suppose you have create a method in adapter like see below :

public ArrayList getSelectedItems() {
        return selectedList
    }

In Activity you have to call this method :
   yourAdapter = YourAdapter(yourList)
   yourAdapter.getSelectedItems()

Simple!!

2. One Other way is using interface.